# How to place order using Stripe Payment REST API in Magento 2.4.4?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, rest-api

working on mobile which use magento 2 REST API For Strip Payment. I am using https://marketplace.magento.com/stripe-stripe-payments.html Extension

Answer (score 0):

Setup your stripe dashboard account here https://dashboard.stripe.com/
Then get your public and secret keys and add them in Admin Dashboard

```
Stores-> Configurations-> Sales-> Payment Methods-> RecomendedSolutions -> Stripe (Configure) -> General Settings
```

Add Test publishable API key & Test secret API key

In Payments Payments Flow Settings Enable cards

Now on checkout stripe will be enabled

for testing purposes. use these cards
https://gist.github.com/rymawby/9b904feec040b25a8034